# Android Emulator default browser can't take screenshot

Tags: selenium, appium, screenshot

My Emulator android phone has android default browser, when appium test the android default browser, it can't take screenshot on failure using TakesScreenshot.How can I to solve it.
I am using Selenium Remote Webdriver as driver instance

```
    public synchronized static void captureScreenshot(WebDriver driver, String screenshotName) {
    try {
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("./Screenshots/"
                + screenshotName + ".png"));
        System.out.println("Screenshot taken");
        filePath=timestamp()+ screenshotName + ".png";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception while taking screenshot "
                + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

CONSOLE LOGS :
Exception while taking screenshot An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: New Command Timeout of 60 seconds expired. Try customizing the timeout using the 'newCommandTimeout' desired capability (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 660.36 seconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23 13:11:40'
System info: host: 'DocASAP-mac-mini.local', ip: '192.168.1.45', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.5', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Session ID: f8bcc2d5-a00d-43c5-8a8a-157d2fbe6260
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{platform=ANDROID, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=Browser, networkConnectionEnabled=true, desired={newCommandTimeout=60, platform=ANDROID, autoAcceptAlerts=true, acceptSslCerts=true, deviceName=192.168.56.101:5555, platformName=Android, browserName=Browser, setAcceptUntrustedCertificates=true, version=5.1.0}, locationContextEnabled=false, deviceUDID=192.168.57.101:5555, version=5.1.0, newCommandTimeout=60, platformVersion=5.1, autoAcceptAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=192.168.57.101:5555, platformName=Android, webStorageEnabled=false, setAcceptUntrustedCertificates=true, warnings={}, takesScreenshot=true}]

Comment: Can you consider updating us what are you trying to do in `filePath=timestamp()+ screenshotName + ".png";`? Do update us if any error along with the error stack trace. Thanks

Comment: This is just another line of function call you can ignore. What the problem is that I have my Genymotion for Android Emulators. It has android default browser, but whenever any failure occurs and i call this captureScreenshot(), this ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE) does not work. No error logs except time out exception occurs.

Comment: Can you consider showing us how you are calling the `captureScreenshot` class please? Thanks

Comment: try {
    HomePage().verifyHomePage();
    // Verify user is able to Login Successfully
    LoginPage().loginWithValidCredentials(usersList, i); 
    LoginPage().logout();
   } catch (AssertionError ex) {
    log.error("Unable to LOGIN", ex);
    CommonFunctions.captureScreenshot(getDriver(), class_name);
    CustomReport.generateReportFile(out, class_name, ex.getMessage(), CommonFunctions.filePath);
    Assert.fail("Test Failed ");
   }

Comment: This class would be called in catch block whenever exception will occur